# SSL, detecting if the browser supports Cloud Flare SSL then redirecting

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have implemented Cloud Flare flexible SSL.

The problem is that not all browsers support the type of certificate Cloud Flare use, and as such some users get warning messages.

I wish to redirect users who can use Cloud Flare SSL to the SSL version of my web site.

I initially tried using .htaccess to redirect http to https, however I need a way to only redirect the browsers that can use the SSL cert.

Cloud Flare provide a list of browsers supported, however its not accurate and I found that Safari on OSX 10.8 is not supported, unless updates are run.

In my software I simply try and load a https website, if I get a positive result I send the user to the https website. But users who directly visit my website need to be directed to the correct site.

I can use PHP, Javascript and htaccess.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through the help section, especially the tour and faq. Your question is a bit vague. Are you having trouble with the redirect or identifying which browsers support this? Try focusing the question and check if it's been asked before.

Comment: CloudFlare "flexible SSL" does not provide end to end encryption.  It gives your visitors the false impression that their connection is encrypted.  According to CloudFlare it should only be used as a last resort; read the NOTE: under Flexible SSL here https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-SSL-Only-mean- Why not use a self-signed cert and run "Full SSL", or better yet, with the cost of certs being under $10 why not use a cert from a real CA?